# Flash 10.1: Can you programmatically adjust the input volume of the Microphone?

Tags: flash, volume, microphone

I need to variably adjust the input volume of the mic in Flash 10.1.  This is not the same as gain, as gain is a software solution, whereas I need to control the mic input level on the microphone itself.  Does someone know if this is possible and how I'd do it?

Answer (score 0):

From Adobe Flash Player there is no API which allows you to control the volume of the microphone. Unfortunately, gain is the only tool in your arsenal.

Comment: I've filed a feature request about this here: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-6070